# How to filter XML elements by date range in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I typically use Nokogiri as my XML parser.

I have the following XML:

```
<albums>
    <aldo_nova album="aldo nova">
        <release_date value="19820401"/>
    </aldo_nova>
    <classix_nouveaux album="Night People"/>
        <release_date value="19820501"/>
    </classix_nouveaux>
    <engligh_beat album="I Just Can't Stop It"/>
        <release_date value="19800501"/>
    </engligh_beat>
</albums>
```

I want to get all albums that were released between 1/1/1980 and 4/15/1982:

```
<aldo_nova album="aldo nova">
    <release_date value="19820401"/>
</aldo_nova>
<engligh_beat album="I Just Can't Stop It"/>
    <release_date value="19800501"/>
</engligh_beat>
```

How do I filter/query the XML by a `release_date` range?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is malformed. After parsing, here's what Nokogiri has to say about it:

```
doc.errors 
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: albums line 1 and classix_nouveaux>,
#     #<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
```

That's because:

```
<classix_nouveaux album="Night People"/>
```

and

```
<engligh_beat album="I Just Can't Stop It"/>
```

are terminated. Instead they should be:

```
<classix_nouveaux album="Night People">
```

and

```
<engligh_beat album="I Just Can't Stop It">
```

You can use CSS or XPath selectors to find exact matches, or even sub-string matches, but neither CSS or XPath understand "ranges" of dates, nor do they have an idea of what a Date is, so you'd have to extract all nodes, convert the date value into a Date object or integer in this case, then compare to the range:

```
date_range = 19800501..19820401
selected_albums = doc.search('//release_date').select { |rd| date_range.include?(rd['value'].to_i) }.map { |rd| rd.parent }

selected_albums.map(&:to_xml)
# => ["<aldo_nova album=\"aldo nova\">\n" +
#    "    <release_date value=\"19820401\"/>\n" +
#    "</aldo_nova>",
#     "<engligh_beat album=\"I Just Can't Stop It\">\n" +
#    "    <release_date value=\"19800501\"/>\n" +
#    "</engligh_beat>"]
```

I think your XML is poorly designed because you have varying tag names for what should be an album. `<album>` should be a child of `<albums>`. I'd recommend something like this:

```
<collection>
  <albums>
    <album band="aldo nova" title="aldo nova" release_date="19820401"/>
    <album band="classix nouveaux" title="Night People" release_date="19820501"/>
    <album band="english beat" title="I Just Can't Stop It" release_date="19800501"/>
  </albums>
</collection>
```

Once the XML is in a standard form, then it becomes easier to navigate and search:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<collection>
  <albums>
    <album band="aldo nova" title="aldo nova" release_date="19820401"/>
    <album band="classix nouveaux" title="Night People" release_date="19820501"/>
    <album band="english beat" title="I Just Can't Stop It" release_date="19800501"/>
  </albums>
</collection>
EOT

doc.search('album').last['title'] # => "I Just Can't Stop It"

band = 'aldo nova'
doc.search("//album[@band='#{band}']").map { |a| a['title'] } # => ["aldo nova"]
```

and searching for dates becomes more straightforward because it's not necessary to find the parent of the node:

```
date_range = 19800501..19820401
selected_albums = doc.search('album').select { |a| date_range.include?(a['release_date'].to_i) }
selected_albums.map(&:to_xml)
# => ["<album band=\"aldo nova\" title=\"aldo nova\" release_date=\"19820401\"/>",
#     "<album band=\"english beat\" title=\"I Just Can't Stop It\" release_date=\"19800501\"/>"]
```

I'd recommend reading some tutorials on XML itself as it's easy to paint ourselves into corners if the data isn't represented logically and correctly.